# The probabilistic method to find out a matrix is MDS

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, determinant

Suppose that $M$ is a matrix of order $n$ such that entries of matrix $M$ com from finite field $GF(2^n)$. The matrix $M$ is called [MDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDS_matrix)
(Maximum Distance Separable) 
matrix if and only if every sub-matrix of $M$ is non-singular over $GF(2^n)$.

For a matrix of order $n$, we should obtain $\sum_{i=1}^n \, {n \choose i }^2$ determinant over $GF(2^n)$, to find out 
 that a matrix is MDS or not. So, when the order of a matrix is  less than $10$, we can use the mentioned definition to check 
 that is it MDS matrix or not. But for large order of matrix, this definition is not applicable.

**My question:**

> Is there a probabilistic method to find out a matrix is MDS or not MDS.

I would be appreciate for any suggestions.

**Edition1:**

With searching, I found one class of MDS matrices over field of real numbers. 
Consider the following companion matrix in the following form

$$
C_n=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 &1 &0 &\cdots &\cdots &0 \\
0 &0 &1 &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &0 \\
0 &\cdots &\cdots &0&0 &1 \\
1 &1 &1 &\cdots &1 &1
\end{array}
\right)_{n\times n}
$$

The $n\times (n-1)$ power of matrix $C_n$ is a MDS matrix and the matrices $C_n^i$, $1\leq i \leq n^2-n-1$ are not MDS matrices. 
 For example, assume the matrix $C_3$ as shown

$$
 C_3=
  \left( \begin {array}{ccc}
  0&1&0\\ 
  0&0&1\\ 
  1&1&1
  \end {array} \right)
 $$

The matrices $C_3^i$, $1\leq i \leq 5$ are not MDS matrix but the matrix $C_3^6$ as follows

$$
 C_3^6= 
  \left( \begin {array}{ccc} 
 4&6&7\\
 7&11&13\\ 
 13&20&24
 \end {array} \right)
 $$
 is a MDS matrix. It means, the entries of $C_3^6$ are non-zero and the determinant of $C_3^6$ is $1$. 
In addition all square sub-matrices of order $2$ of matrix  $C_3^6$ have non-zero determinant.

**Edition2:**

As an answer to  @Daniel McLaury comment, you can check that the matrices $C_3^j$, $15 \leq j \leq 18$, are not MDS. For example,
 the matrix $C_3^{17}$ is as follows

$$
 C_3^{17}=
  \left[ \begin {array}{ccc}
  3136&4841&5768\\ 
5768& 8904&10609\\
 10609&16377&19513
 \end {array} \right] 
 $$

the determinant of the following two sub-matrices of $C_3^{17}$ are zero

$$
 \begin{array}{ccc}
 \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 
 5768&8904\\
10609&16377
\end {array} \right]
 &, & 
  \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 
  3136&5768\\
  5768&10609
\end {array} \right] 
 \end{array}
 $$

In fact, design of MDS matrix is on the finite field. I just made this example in the field of real numbers to clarify my question. 
 You can see the original form of my question with example,
 in my [Mathover](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258350/the-probabilistic-method-to-find-out-a-matrix-is-mds?noredirect=1#comment637716_258350).

Comment: Given that 100% of matrices have this property, I don't know if probabilistic algorithms are likely to give you any further information.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Please see the new edition.

Comment: I see.  I think it just confuses things to do everything over $\mathbb{R}$ and then mention that you're actually interested in finite fields at the end.  I don't specifically know if it matters, but are you trying to do this over *every* finite field, or only $\mathbb{F}_p$, or only $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ or something?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury In cryptography, just $GF(2^n)$ can be used. I made an example in the field of real numbers because your first comment was absolutely wrong. I do not know why do you said "100% of matrices have this property:!

Comment: Do you understand that there is a difference between "100% of matrices have this property" and "every matrix has this property"?  There are of course matrices that do not have this property, but they constitute 0% of all matrices under any (reasonable) distribution.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Can I ask you that proof your claim that matrices that are not MDS constitute 0% of all matrices  under any (reasonable) distribution, with math discussion?

Comment: Yes, but post it as a separate question because it's a bit too long for a comment.

Comment: If you want the short answer: because the set of non-MDS $m \times n$ matrices is a union of finitely many hypersurfaces, thus it has dimension $m n - 1$, and a reasonable probability measure on an $mn$-dimensional space shouldn't assign a positive probability to anything with dimension less than $mn$.

Comment: Of course this only makes sense if you're working over $\mathbb{R}$.  Your question is completely reasonable given that you're working over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$, but you should add that to your question and remove the stuff about the reals.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury You right. your suggestions was added to question. Thanks.